# Fail to Load Map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am following [Android Google Map](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm) tutorial , But here i am getting this error **"FAIL TO LOAD MAP"** when my program runs in Micromax P255 & it is also not working Emulator. I seen some solutions here but could not solve my problem.
Thanx

My [XML](http://pastie.org/8721208)

My [Activity class](http://pastie.org/8721212)

My [Manifest](http://pastie.org/8721214)

Comment: have you added Google plays services as a reference project to your project...

Comment: Have you added the Sha1 fingerprint in google console.I mean in google api console you have to enable support for maps.

Comment: @vinayManeti yes. i have added Google plays service in my project.

Comment: @AdityaKamath I am following http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.html this tutorial.